# Android sqlite query value to a equation

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public String val2;
public String val3;

private void sumsp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Company obj1 = new Company();
        String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();

        Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
                "SELECT avg(Price) FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
                new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
        sumw.moveToFirst();
        val2 = sumw.getString(0);
        String result = val2+val3;
        text2.setText(result);
    }

    private void sum() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Company obj1 = new Company();
        String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();

        Cursor sum = dbObject.rawQuery(
                "SELECT Sum(Volume) FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
                new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
        sum.moveToFirst();
        val3 = sum.getString(0);
        text.setText(sum.getString(0));
    }
```

what i want to do is... get the val3 value and multiply it in the sumsp() val2.

result = (val2*val3*1.02252544)/val2;

and display it on a textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the whole thing with one query:

```
Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
        "SELECT avg(Price) * sum(Volume) FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
        new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
```

So you probably don't even need `val1`, `val2`, `sumsp()`, or `sum()` at all.

Comment: yes thank you, but actually i want the above full equation to use

Comment: @Loshan: Then update the query to match your edits: `SELECT (avg(Price) * sum(Volume) * 1.02252544) / sum(Volume) ...`

Comment: small thing to know.... the answers are getting as Eg: 12.898293
how to get the answer as for #.## two decimal points

Comment: @Loshan: You should handle the formatting issues in Java, just pull the value out as a `double` and then round/truncate/format when you convert the `double` to a `String`.

Comment: hey i got it in this way, thank you for the support round(avg(Price) * sum(Volume),2)